# How to change the button's text on openFileDialog ShowDialog window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the text written on the button in the ShowDialog window from Open to somthing else..
How can I do that?

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
     ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404539 out. But instead of changing position, you need to send `WM_SETTEXT` message to change the caption of the button, when you get the button's id.